# Link won't open in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble using the jQuery BlockUI plugin.

What I'm trying to do is have a clickable link in the content lock, but even when I add target="_blank", it won't send to the URL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            $('a:not(.content-locker)').click(function(e) {
                if (a == 0) {
                    $.blockUI({ 
                        message: $('#content-locker'), 
                        css: { top: '20%' } 
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I had to edit this a tad bit to work on my page, but this solved it.